# Keep aspect ratio figure

Tags: matlab, resize, position, figure, aspect-ratio

How to resize an image keeping the ratio between width and height when the figure is resized (F3/F4 should keep constant)?

```
f=figure();
F1=300;F2=300;F3=600;F4=300;
f.Position=[F1 F2 F3 F4];
```

Comment: Are you wanting to keep an image aspect ratio the same as the figure window it's in is resized?

Comment: No, the figure window itself. This is a GUI figure.

Comment: Do you mean when the figure is resized _in the program_ or when it is _manually resized by the user_?

Comment: When it is manually resized by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following feedback function to achieve what you want:

```
set(f,'SizeChangedFcn',@(src, callbackdata) onSizeChanged(src, F3, F4));

function onSizeChanged(src, F3, F4)
   pos = src.Position;
   scale = (pos(3)/F3 + pos(4)/F4)/2; % estimate the desired scale factor
   % scale = min(pos(3)/F3, pos(4)/F4); % alternative
   pos(3) = scale*F3;
   pos(4) = scale*F4;
   src.Position = pos;
end
```

An alternative may be to use [`pbaspect`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/aspect-ratio-for-2-d-axes.html), but this will change the aspect ratio of the plot, not the window itself.

Comment: Thanks! onSizeChanged is what I was looking for, however sometimes the figure enters in oscillation because the uicontrols have normalized units.